# I am getting this error while trying to deploy my nextjs application

Tags: npm, next.js, deployment, build

This is the next.config.js file of the nextjs application that I am building. The site has a single page with multiple components. The files are here: https://github.com/CodingLife1024/substainify

```
Run npx --no-install next export
  npx --no-install next export
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_PAGES: true
 ⨯ 
    The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export
  
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The error that is coming up is

```
Run npx --no-install next export
  npx --no-install next export
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_PAGES: true
 ⨯ 
    The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export
  
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to manually run this

```
Run npx --no-install next export
```

This gives the error:

```
 ⨯ 
    The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall npm and npx also.

Comment: Have you tried doing the thing it suggests instead of the same thing over and over again?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is the next.config.js. ```/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',

  // Optional configurations can be added here
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
``` it already contains the "output: export" and it also is giving the error ``` ⨯ 
    The "next export" command has been removed in favor of "output: export" in next.config.js. Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export```.

Comment: You're calling the `next export` command so yes of course it's saying that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so what do I edit to get rid of the error ?

Comment: ...stop calling the command that has been removed? Instead of running `npx --no-install next export`, _don't_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to deploy it to github pages, the process calls it automatically

Comment: Presumably you're referring to e.g. https://github.com/CodingLife1024/substainify/actions/runs/7806685969/job/21293569317, in which case you need to **change the process** (also your commit habits: https://github.com/CodingLife1024/substainify/commits/master/). Realistically the error tells you everything there is to tell you: **`next export` no longer exists**, so you can't keep using it.